gnome-shell icon grid customization
I applied a custom theme to my fedora 39 OS, but I am not able to change the icon size of App grid .icon-grid.
gnome-shell.css:
...

.icon-grid {
  spacing: 30px;
  -shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 136px;
  -shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 136px;
}
  
.icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px;
}

...

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a specific class name to make it work?
I changed some other element styles, and changes have been applied.
